# linker error on arm neon code

Tags: arm, neon, sbrk

I am working on ARM neon code using c intrinsics.  When I compile the file I keep getting the following errors:

> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot find entry symbol
>    _start; defaulting to 00008020
>
> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function 'exit':
>   exit.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to '_exit'
>
> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function '_fst
>   at_r':
>   fstatr.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to '_fstat'
>
> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-openr.o): In function '_open
>   _r':openr.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to '_open'
>
> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function '_sbrk
>   _r':
>   sbrkr.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to '_sbrk'
>
> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function '_wri
>   te_r':writer.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to '_write'
>
> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function '_clo
>   se_r':
>   closer.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to '_close'
>
> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function '_is
>   atty_r':isattyr.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to '_isatty'
>
> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function '_lse
>   ek_r':lseekr.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to '_lseek'
>
> c:/program files (x86)/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
>   bi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function '_read
>   _r':readr.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to '_read'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Can anyone tell me how to rectify these errors?.  All I know is that I have to explicitly define the functions `isatty()`, `fstat` etc.  But I don't know where to define them

Comment: add some more information like the Makefile etc.

Comment: It looks like you're not linking against glibc? Is that you intention? Is this a bare metal system or a user mode linux app or what?